# Correct configuration of path mappings in PhpStorm using symlink

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Scenario:
In my local Apache server I create symlinks to my real directories structures. For example,

```
/var/www/project -> /home/Workspace/project
```

I successfully configured xdebug to use with PHP.

But I can't configure path mappings in PhpStorm.

In PhpStorm path mappings dialog I enable `Use path mappings (select if the server is remote or symlinks are used)`, and map `/home/Workspace/project` in `File/Directory` column to `/var/www/project` in column `Absolute path on the server`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In theory (considering the limited info) it all looks OK. I suggest to collect and check xdebug log and see what exact path is used there (check the path as well as letter capitalisation). If anything -- delete that `PHP | Server` entry and let PhpStorm help to set it up for you (on incoming request, if no matching server entry present, IDE will offer some help to set it up).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. I've removed the `PHP | Server` entry and accept PhpStorm suggestion. In fact deselect "Use path mappings (select if the server is remote or symlinks are used)" and ignore new warning messages about path mappings.